# using if elif and else to print different statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I have created a code in thonny that takes 3 inputs to determine the price of an item. I also want to be able to provide a discount to the price if it meets certain requirement and only one discount is eligible and to print the results of the discount. if if no discount is eligible I want print just the price of the item.

Please see my code below what I have tried

```
if sqFt > BIG_DESK:
    if wood == 'oak' or wood == 'mahog':
        discount = DISC_1
        discAmnt = discount * price
        discPrice = price - discAmnt

elif wood == 'oak' or drawers > DISC_DRAWER:
    discount = DISC_2
    discAmnt = discount * price
    discPrice = price - discAmnt

elif price > DISC_PRICE:
    discount = DISC_3
    discAmnt = discount * price
    discPrice = price - discAmnt

print("\nThe price of the desk is $", format(price,',.2f'))
print("\nThe discounted price is $", format(discPrice,',.2f'))
print("\nYou qualified for a", format(discount,'.0%'),"and saved",format(discAmnt,',.2f'))


else:
    print("\nThe price of the desk is $", format(price,',.2f'))
```

As stated before, if there is a discount able to be applied I want it to print the price, the price minus the discount, and the discount and discount amount.

I keep getting error at the else statement with error statement `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Please provide the full traceback with a [mcve]

Comment: What's the whole error? _the stuffs after "(most recent call last)_

Comment: Hey @Aaron Sherman : Is your indentation right?

Comment: You have a simple indentation error; the `print` after the last `elif` which is outdented terminates the entire `if` block.

Comment: I'm sorry the error is a syntax error at the else statement

Comment: after indenting the 3 print statements it doesn't return any print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple indentation error; the `print` after the last `elif` which is outdented terminates the entire `if` block.

Depending on what you hope for the code to actually do, either indent the `print` so that it is part of the `elif`, or put the `else` before the other `print` statements. If the thing in the `else` should control whether to print something after the other prints, create a variable which controls a second `if / else` block, perhaps like this:

```py
eligible = True

if sqFt > BIG_DESK:
    if wood in ['oak', 'mahog']:   # notice also "in" operator
        discount = DISC_1
        discAmnt = discount * price
        discPrice = price - discAmnt
elif wood == 'oak' or drawers > DISC_DRAWER:
    discount = DISC_2
    discAmnt = discount * price
    discPrice = price - discAmnt
elif price > DISC_PRICE:
    discount = DISC_3
    discAmnt = discount * price
    discPrice = price - discAmnt
else:
    eligible = False

print("The price of the desk is $", format(price,',.2f'))
if eligible:
    print("The discounted price is $", format(discPrice,',.2f'))
    print("You qualified for a", format(discount,'.0%'),"and saved",format(discAmnt,',.2f'))
```

Comment: I took out the pesky `\n` characters. If you want lots of empty lines on your screen, a lone `print()` will also produce one.